# Smiley? Where do they come from?

Tags: facebook, chat

How does the chat application like that found in Facebook(for example), uses smiley's? That is my question is how does these symbols(smiley's) come from? Do they have any ASCII characters, because when we type ":)"(without quotes) it shows us the happy smiley? Where does these symbols reside from, what actually is going behind the scenes?

And the same option is not found in the comment areas of Facebook.

Correct me if am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

They search for smileys within the text, and then replace them with  tags that contain a URL to the correct smiley.